# How to bulk insert by checking every row in datagrid if there is data in some columns

Tags: c#, asp.net

The data grid in the front end interface looks like below. At least one of the color textbox should have value when the insert button is clicked. And insert a new row if there is data in any one of the color columns. And the table design in the database is like below. The status column refers to the colors in the interface. When the button is clicked, it should do a bulk insert, where it loops through every row and if there is data in the color columns, it should create at least 3 records per row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSWXj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8kIr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L5ZN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjZ2J.png)

Comment: In the 2nd row example, we saved and inserted two rows, and later on go back and edit and add say 2018 to yellow that was blank. Do we now insert all 3 rows again, or only the one row (having to check if existing rows already exist then???? I mean loop though the first grid, and adding the rows to the 2nd grid/table is easy. But if 2nd rows already exist, and we are to only say add one row because we put say 2018 in the empty yellow column, then now we can't just add 3 new rows, since 2 rows already will exist, correct??? Easy to insert the rows, but MUCH more difficult if rows already exist

Comment: You are right. When the user edits a row, 2 things can happen, edit existing year or add new year to a color. So, we need to check when editing existing data, if there is any change comapred to previous value and update if there is or else put a message, there is no change in the data. And insert a new row if it was null before for a specific color. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we can assume this:

First, the markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" Width="30%">
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category"          />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Green"><ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtGreen" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("Green") %>' Width="50px" ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Yellow"><ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtYellow" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("Yellow") %>' Width="50px" ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Red"><ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtRed" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("Red") %>' Width="50px" ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Done - add data" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdAdd_Click" />
```

So, above is a grid, and a button below to send data to the 2nd table.

Our code to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblProducts ORDER BY ID";
        DataTable rstData = MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And we say now have this:

[image]

So, our add button code then becomes this:

```
protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblProductsList WHERE ID = 0";
    DataTable rstTarget = MyRst(strSQL);

    foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox tGreen = (TextBox)gRow.FindControl("txtGreen");
        TextBox tYellow = (TextBox)gRow.FindControl("txtYellow");
        TextBox tRed = (TextBox)gRow.FindControl("txtRed");

        if (tGreen.Text != "")
        {
            DataRow MyRow = rstTarget.NewRow();
            MyRow["ProductName"] = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
            MyRow["Catagory"] = gRow.Cells[1].Text;
            MyRow["Status"] = 1;
            MyRow["Year"] = tGreen.Text;
            rstTarget.Rows.Add(MyRow);
        }

        if (tYellow.Text != "")
        {
            DataRow MyRow = rstTarget.NewRow();
            MyRow["ProductName"] = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
            MyRow["Catagory"] = gRow.Cells[1].Text;
            MyRow["Status"] = 2;
            MyRow["Year"] = tYellow.Text;
            rstTarget.Rows.Add(MyRow);
        }
        if (tRed.Text != "")
        {
            DataRow MyRow = rstTarget.NewRow();
            MyRow["ProductName"] = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
            MyRow["Catagory"] = gRow.Cells[1].Text;
            MyRow["Status"] = 3;
            MyRow["Year"] = tRed.Text;
            rstTarget.Rows.Add(MyRow);
        }
    }
    // done, now send (save) all rows back to database
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(rstTarget);
        }
    }
}
```

And I did use a helper routine - that just returns a data table for given sql.

That was this:

```
    DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Albert. This makes total sense. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Do we not have to use a insert command?

Comment: No, any changes/update, any delete, and any insert to the rstTarget table is done with ONE single command -of da.Update(rstTarget). So, we are inserting by creating a new row of data with rstTarget.NewRow(). That creates a new row, we set the column values, and then add this new row into rstTarget with rstTarget.Rows.Add(MyRow). After we add the rows to this table, then with one command we save rstTarget back to the sql database.  The code as posted does work.  You question wanted ONE bulk insert, and that's what we are doing here. We can add 3 or 20 rows. Then the ONE update command saves.

Comment: Ok. So, I believe there should be a button each for insert, update and delete. Also, I had responded to your question about making edits. You are right. When the user edits a row, 2 things can happen, edit existing year or add new year to a color. So, we need to check when editing existing data, if there is any change compared to previous value and update if there is or else put a message, there is no change in the data. And insert a new row if it was null before for a specific color. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want and need multiple buttons (to confuse the hell out of the user?). We have a simple grid. User enters values in those text boxes, and then hits the one button to write out all the required rows of data. Why would you abuse and torture your users for what amounts to a simple button click? People edit word, and one save button. People edit Excel and one save button. People make changes on a web site and one submit button. To do any other kind of UI here makes no sense at all. Why complicate matters with multiple buttons? Users don't think like developers or how databases work.

Comment: As for if the data already exists in 2nd table? Well again, from a UI point of view, the user does not care one hoot. If they edit, nor not, or change or not? Don't care from a user point of view. They see some data, and hit save. But we the developers most certainly have to cook up a easy way to deal with already existing rows. Even if they make no changes - who cares? Whatever they see, and then hit submit or save is all THEY require. The real problem here is the un-normalized first table - that's a bad design. So, 2nd part would be to deal with existing rows - do they have a PK?

Comment: This suggests (unless we want to write some REALLY messy code), that we need to pull into that grid display data source the PK's of the target table. By doing that, we can save a boatload of complexity here. Out of time right now, but hopefully a day or so I can find the time to come back here as to how we can deal if rows exist and modify our existing code a bit to deal with as such. I mean, we can brute force code out this and check for the existing rows, but by pulling such information into our display grid, we save a lot of code.

Comment: As for adding a row? We can drop in a add row button below the grid. User can click on that, and we add a row to the grid, and then we use/allow the same editing and the ONE simple button to save. This not only keeps things clean and simple for the end user, but also keeps the UI simple, and that means FAR less code and FAR less confusing to the user. In their mind, and from their point of view - they just have to hit submit and they are done. But, adding rows and that UI is a VERY different question then the basic question as to how we can add rows based on your question. Posted code works.

Comment: I totally agree with you. And that is why I am designing the interface where the user can enter all the data in one row versus multiple rows. I would like to provide some clarification with my original question. And I have uploaded the interface design and details. Can you take a look at it? All the inputs by the user is a dropdown, not a textbox. And the add button adds to the datagrid view, so the user can make sure it looks good before doing the bulk insert. The user does not want to enter the color status for the year column.  I hope this makes sense